# I cannot deploy only the build folder of a ReactJS application in the Azure Linux environment

Tags: reactjs, linux, azure, deployment, devops

In some tutorials I found to deploy a ReactJs application in the Azure environment, a Windows machine is used, but I would like to use a Linux machine, in which case I can only send all project sources to the server.

../src
../public

I would like to know if it is possible to deploy only the contents of the build folder. Because I'm trying for days and I can't get it.

Comment: Hi Will, please add more info and details about your question, in order to make it easier for the community to help you. Currently there is a lack of details here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will explain what I have done.
First, you should change "homepage" value to "." in package.json
[image]

after that, you set the route path with "/"
[image]

and then "yarn -s build" or "npm run-script build" in your terminal.
then the build folder will be created.

copy all files in "build" folder and paste it to your /var/www/html(it is dynamic)
I can help you remotely.

I hope this answer helps you.